# wget: unable to resolve host address “www.cmake.org”

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, cmake, centos

I'm trying to install cmake at my CentOS 6.2, but for some reason i get this error message : 
Resolving www.cmake.org... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address “www.cmake.org”. 
This is the command i wrote : 
wget http://www.cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.3.tar.gz

Comment: Looks like you're having some DNS issues. That command works fine for me. Make sure you're connected to the internet. Try `ping www.google.com` and see if that works.

Comment: Yes you r right, i can't seem to be able to ping google.com. Just to let u know i'm ssh to this virtual machine

Comment: It's probably your VM software networking settings. Most standard setups work with Bridged Networking. To make sure it's actually the internet and not the DNS, try `ping 8.8.8.8`. If it's the internet, that won't work, but if it's the DNS, it will.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably old, but here is how it worked for me:
1. Comment out the IPV6 properties on /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
`#IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes`
`#IPV6INIT=yes`
2. Restart your network service.
`service network restart`
Then wget worked like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my case this was because of wrong entry  of DNS server in  my local "/etc/resolv.conf".

I have added the proper entry in "/etc/resolv.conf" and then restarted the netwrork using "# service network restart".

Then I was able to use "wget".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am necro-posting, but, I found a solution to this, and the solutions is that, you may have set-up a static ip which is not working in Raspberry Pi (basically it doesn't have internet access), So, removing the "ip" line from "/boot/cmdline.txt/" seems to helped me.